# Move txt file from multiple folders and rename

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have multiple folders and within each folder a file names "tabled_output.tab". I would like to move this file into a new folder and rename the file with the original folder name. I need to run this in a loop to move all "tabled_output.tab" files.

This is what I have so far:

```
 cd /storage/home/iul116/.ssh/poblacionesmaices/inputfiles_osr/Output/
 ls > razas.txt
 cd /storage/home/iul116/.ssh/poblacionesmaices/inputfiles_osr/Output/(x)
 mv tabled_output.tab (x)
 mv (x) /storage/home/iul116/.ssh/poblacionesmaices/inputfiles_osr/Results/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Bash script might help. It should be run from the parent directory of the folders which include the files to move.

```
DESTDIR=tables
FILENAME=tabled_output.tab

mkdir -p $DESTDIR # -p flag => skip if directory already exists

# Search all folders in the current directory
for dir in `ls -d */`; do
    dir=${dir/\/} # remove trailing slash
    TMPNAME=$dir/$FILENAME # destination file
    # Check if a file called 'tabled_output.tab' exists
    # in the relevant sub-directory
    if [ -e $TMPNAME ]; then
        # If so, move it to the destination directory
        mv $TMPNAME $DESTDIR/$dir.tab
    fi
done
```

**Update:** Using `ls -d */` to retrieve the list of subfolders is not ideal - as Stephen P mentioned in the comments.

Comment: It's dangerous to use the output of `ls` to process files or directories: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs -- There is a [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/1986) and several good answers about why you shouldn't do this on the [Unix & Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). `find -type d` optionally with `-name some*thing*` (and/or other criteria) is safer and usually more efficient.

Comment: @StephenP: I appreciate the correction. I will update my answer as soon as I can.

Comment: @StephenP: I understand the risks of using `ls` to retrieve the list of sub-directories, but haven't had time to fully explore the alternatives. I have marked the answer as 'community wiki', so if you or anyone else wants to edit it feel free.

Comment: Hi @StephenP! the best way to avoid using ´ls´ to retrieve sub-directories is to use find! check out my answer and let me know what you think

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a single command:

```
find "<PATH_TO_OUTPUT>" -name "*" -type d -print -exec bash -c 'cd "$1";current_dir=${PWD##*/};mv tabled_output.tab <PATH_TO_RESULTS>"$current_dir".tab' -- {} \;
```

This script searchs in every folder inside the folder Output and moves (if exists)
the file tabled_output.tab to the folder Results (you must give your absolute path to this folder). Changing the name of the file for the name of the folder that contains it.

In your case I believe it would work using:

```
<PATH_TO_OUTPUT> = /storage/home/iul116/.ssh/poblacionesmaices/inputfiles_osr/Output/
```

and

```
<PATH_TO_RESULTS> = /storage/home/iul116/.ssh/poblacionesmaices/inputfiles_osr/Results/
```

Sorry for my bad english.